# Do something when user aborts connection (Sinatra + Thin)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, eventmachine, thin

I'm writing an app that sometimes requires very long-running DB requests. I'd like to execute some code if the client reloads or closes the page to do things with the DB requests.

I was hoping that Rack would have hooks into this sorta thing, but apparently from what I've seen this is a level deeper than Rack goes.

So far, the only hook I can find is into thin itself, by monkey-patching the unbind function in the thin Connection class:

```
module Thin
  class Connection < EventMachine::Connection

    def unbind

      # DO something here

      @request.async_close.succeed if @request.async_close
      @response.body.fail if @response.body.respond_to?(:fail)
      @backend.connection_finished(self)
    end
  end
end
```

This overrides Thin's unbind function and lets me hook into the disconnect called by EventMachine.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You should consider making long running requests asynchronous. It would be cleaner design and would solve your present problem as well.

Comment: I actually am running the request asynchonously, using EventMachine, em-syncrhony, and sinatra-synchrony. This still doesn't solve my problem though - I want to know when the user stops caring about the results from the DB, regardless of whether or not the request is synchronous.

Comment: From what I understand, sinatra-synchrony only run requests concurrently. Therefore I still think @Gunjan advice applies.

Comment: Like I mentioned previously, my problem has nothing to do with whether or not the request is synchronous. The problem is that some of the db queries are so massive that they could render the db useless, and I need to be able to kill them if the user leaves the page. This problem exists regardless of whether or not the db request is performed asynchronously.

Comment: You can use the async_close method above. As an example, have a look at [Sinatra::ExtendedRack#setup_close](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L190)

Comment: If you use a [Sinatra::Helpers::Streaming](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L393) response you can setup callbacks which are called (deferred) on the above async_close call.

This is handy to do some clean up when the client disconnects (e.g. `EventSource#close` on the javascripts side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I've found that Thin provides a mechanism for replacing the 'backend', or how the server connects to the client. I'm using that, combined with values in the rack env to deal with specific request instances and know if I need to kill a query or not:

```
class Backend < Thin::Backends::TcpServer

  def initialize(host, port, options={})
    super(host, port)
  end

  def connection_finished(connection)
    super(connection)

    if connection.request.env["query_killer"]
      connection.request.env["query_killer"].kill
    end

  end

end
```

This can be included into thin via command-line arguments:

```
thin start  -r 'my_module/backend' --backend MyModule::Backend
```